# Using ExtJS 5 with OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers, ext-js

I'm developing a web application using ExtJS 5 and OpenLayers 3. For displaying map I used the Google API and it worked fine. But when I switched to OpenLayers 3 I could not find any Ext.ux components for OpenLayers 3. For Google API there is Ext.ux.GMapPanel in ExtJS 5. For OpenLayers 3 the only component I could find was [this](https://github.com/tschortsch/Ext.ux.OpenLayersMap/blob/master/ux/OpenLayersMap.js). But since it uses OpenLayers 3 I cannot use that. Can anyone help me ?

**Update**

I am looking for a component like [this](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/source/GMapPanel.html) for OpenLayers 3

Answer (score 4):

You might find the [GeoExt3 project](http://geoext.github.io/geoext3/) interesting, especially the [`GeoExt.component.Map` (API docs)](http://geoext.github.io/geoext3/master/docs/#!/api/GeoExt.component.Map)

In case you use an older version of OpenLayers (your original question makes me think you actually use v2.x), you can e.g. use [GeoExt2.1](https://geoext.github.io/geoext2/)

Comment: I am using OpenLayers 3. Is ther any way to use  OpenLayers 3 with ExtJS 5 without GeoEXT ?